# What does the subscript of a supremum mean?

Tags: probability

I understand that P(...) means the probability of $\hat{i}$ not equal to $i^*$, and supreme means the maximum of a set, but when they go together, I don't know what they mean. Can someone help me translate the following inequality in English so that I can understand it better? Much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: More details, please.

Comment: The $\mu$s can be events; if to each of them is associated a probability, the $\sup$ function will choose one of them.

Comment: The $\mu$s can be parameter values.  As they range over their possible values, the probability changes, but is always less than or equal to $\delta$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I didn't understand the details at the time I posted this question; really wished I could have provided more details. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Supremum refers to the maximum over a set.

To start with something simpler, consider the following maximum notation:

$$y\geq\max_xf(x)$$

which means that $y$ is greater than $f(x)$ regardless of the value of $x$.

Similarly, the supremum notation mentioned in the question

$$\delta \geq \sup_{\mu_1, \cdots, \mu_n}\mathbb{P}(\hat{i} \neq i^*)$$

means that $\delta$ is greater than $\mathbb{P}(\hat{i} \neq i^*)$ regardless of the value of each mean in a set of means $\{\mu_1, \cdots, \mu_n\}$.

The inequality would have been easier to understand if the set of means in the subscript was surrounded by set brackets.